# Functional way to stack list of 2d matrices into 3d matrix

Tags: r, functional-programming

After a clever `lapply`, I'm left with a list of 2-dimensional matrices.

For example:

```
set.seed(1)
test <- replicate( 5,  matrix(runif(25),ncol=5), simplify=FALSE )
> test
[[1]]
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.8357088 0.29589546 0.9994045 0.2862853 0.6973738
[2,] 0.2377494 0.14704832 0.0348748 0.7377974 0.6414624
[3,] 0.3539861 0.70399206 0.3383913 0.8340543 0.6439229
[4,] 0.8568854 0.10380669 0.9150638 0.3142708 0.9778534
[5,] 0.8537634 0.03372777 0.6172353 0.4925665 0.4147353

[[2]]
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 0.1194048 0.9833502 0.9674695 0.6687715 0.1928159
[2,] 0.5260297 0.3883191 0.5150718 0.4189159 0.8967387
[3,] 0.2250734 0.2292448 0.1630703 0.3233450 0.3081196
[4,] 0.4864118 0.6232975 0.6219023 0.8352553 0.3633005
[5,] 0.3702148 0.1365402 0.9859542 0.1438170 0.7839465

[[3]]
...
```

I'd like to turn that into a 3-dimensional array:

```
set.seed(1)
replicate( 5,  matrix(runif(25),ncol=5) )
```

Obviously, if I'm using replicate I can just turn on `simplify`, but `sapply` does not simplify the result properly, and `stack` fails utterly.  `do.call(rbind,mylist)` turns it into a 2d matrix rather than 3d array.

I can do this with a loop, but I'm looking for a neat and functional way to handle it.

The closest way I've come up with is:

```
array( do.call( c, test ), dim=c(dim(test[[1]]),length(test)) )
```

But I feel like that's inelegant (because it disassembles and then reassembles the array attributes of the vectors, and needs a lot of testing to make safe (e.g. that the dimensions of each element are the same).

Comment: there's the abind package

Comment: I disagree that your 'closest way' is inelegant and I further disagree that it needs "a lot" of testing. It's clearly correct and you do need either `do.call(c, test)` or `unlist(test)` and after that its totally straightforward.

Comment: @Dwin maybe I'm too hard on my own code.  But taking advantage of the fundamentals of vectors/matrices always makes me nervous.  Point taken, though, that it might not be a terrible solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `abind` package and then use `abind(test, along = 3)`

```
library(abind)
testArray <- abind(test, along = 3)
```

Or you could use `simplify = 'array'` in a call to `sapply`, (instead of `lapply`). `simplify = 'array'` is not the same as `simplify = TRUE`, as it will change the argument `higher` in `simplify2array`

eg

```
foo <- function(x) matrix(1:10, ncol = 5)
# the default is simplify = TRUE
sapply(1:5, foo)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    2    2    2    2    2
 [3,]    3    3    3    3    3
 [4,]    4    4    4    4    4
 [5,]    5    5    5    5    5
 [6,]    6    6    6    6    6
 [7,]    7    7    7    7    7
 [8,]    8    8    8    8    8
 [9,]    9    9    9    9    9
[10,]   10   10   10   10   10
# which is *not* what you want
# so set `simplify = 'array'
sapply(1:5, foo, simplify = 'array')
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10

, , 4

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10

, , 5

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    5    7    9
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10
```

Comment: The first argument to `abind` may be a list, so you don't need `do.call`: `testArray <- abind (test, along = 3)`

Comment: Marking this an the answer since it hits both `abind` and `,simplify='array'`.

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
simplify2array(test)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me when using with the result of `foreach`

Answer (score 4):

An array is simply an atomic vector with dimensions. Each of the matrix components of `test` is really just a vector with dimensions too. Hence the simplest solution I can think of is to unroll the list `test` into a vector and convert that to an array using `array` and suitably supplied dimensions.

```
set.seed(1)
foo <- replicate( 5,  matrix(runif(25),ncol=5) )
tmp <- array(unlist(test), dim = c(5,5,5))

> all.equal(foo, tmp)
[1] TRUE
> is.array(tmp)
[1] TRUE
> dim(tmp)
[1] 5 5 5
```

If you don't want to hardcode the dimensions, we have to make some assumptions but can easily fill in the dimension from `test`, e.g.

```
tmp2 <- array(unlist(test), dim = c(dim(test[[1]]), length(test)))

> all.equal(foo, tmp2)
[1] TRUE
```

This assumes that the dimensions of each component are all the same, but then I don't see how you could put sub-matrices into a 3-d array if that condition doesn't hold.

This may seem hacky, to unroll the list, but this is simply exploiting how R handles matrices and arrays as vectors with dimensions.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Sort of yes. Sorry; I looked for Answers using `array` and didn't see any, and wanting to provide some explanation I added an answer. Note you have an error in the first chunk - it should be `c(dim(test[[1]]), 5)`

Comment: no sweat at all, and certainly, your answer offers a good bit more explanation than mine does.  Thanks for the catch, edited my mistake

Comment: If one would like to reshape the 3d array in order to make the first dimension of the array corresponding to the length of the list, this line would do it: testMat <- aperm(tmp2, c(3,1,2))

Answer (score 2):

```
test2 <- unlist(test)
dim(test2) <- c(dim(test[[1]]),5)
```

---

or if you do not know the expected size ahead of time:

```
dim3 <- c(dim(test[[1]]), length(test2)/prod(dim(test[[1]])))
dim(test2) <- dim3
```

Comment: your previous answer has now been incorporated into mine (your new answer is very neat)

Comment: @mnel, thanks, I had actually just noticed the use of `simplify="array"` recently in the documentation to `sapply` and then saw that it was also in `Replicate`.  But I had misread the OP's comment about *not* using Replicate, hence I deleted my first answer upon re-reading.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta `simplify="array"` actually would solve my problem 9 times out of 10.  Thanks!