# How to convert a list of matrices to a 3D matrix?

Tags: r, list, matrix

[Functional way to stack list of 2d matrices into 3d matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533359/functional-way-to-stack-list-of-2d-matrices-into-3d-matrix)

↑ From this Q I learned I could use `simplify2array` for this task.

However, it doesn't solve my problem. Unfortunately, I simply don't know how to describe the issue without showing it on an example…

```
l = list()
l[[1]] = matrix(1:110, nrow=10)
l[[2]] = matrix(110:1, nrow=10)
l = simplify2array(l)
dim(l)
```

This prints:

```
10 11 2
```

Problem is, I would like the dimensions to be set in a different manner. I would like `dim(l)` to print instead:

```
2 11 10
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aperm` as a generalized transpose (where `a` is as in the Note at the end).

```
aa <- aperm(a, 3:1)
dim(aa)
## [1]  2 11 10
```

### Note

We assume that the input `a` is:

```
l = list()
l[[1]] = matrix(1:110, nrow=10)
l[[2]] = matrix(110:1, nrow=10)
a <- simplify2array(l)
```