# How to create a 3D array from 2D matrices in R?

Tags: r, arrays

I would like to create a 3D array based on a couple of 2D matrices in R, but I have no idea. Let's say we have the following three matrices:

```
matrix1 <- matrix(1:1, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
matrix2 <- matrix(2:2, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
matrix3 <- matrix(3:3, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
```

I would like to know how to create one `[1:3, 1:5, 1:5]` array, as a combination of the three matrices. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't have the matrices floating around in your workspace but collected in a list, you find several alternatives here: [Functional way to stack list of 2d matrices into 3d matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533359/functional-way-to-stack-list-of-2d-matrices-into-3d-matrix)

Comment: what is your expected outcome ... does `abind:::abind(matrix1,matrix2,matrix3, along=0)` satisfy?

Comment: Thank you very much. I would try your methods later but I will adopt arkun's method first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can concatenate the matrixes together into a vector, use `array` to construct a 3D array with specified `dim`

```
ar1 <- array(c(matrix1, matrix2, matrix3), c(5, 5, 3))
```